Why is feature typing a form of specialization in KerML/SysML?
SysML v2 is based on the new Kernel Modeling Language (KerML).
In KerML, feature typing relates a feature (such as Person::employer) to its co-domain (such as Organization).
As a type, a feature semantically corresponds to a binary relation formed as a subset of the Cartesian product of its domain and its co-domain.
In KerML, feature typing is a form of specialization, instead of a plain relationship. This implies that its special type, the feature concerned, specializes its general type, the feature's co-domain. That is, employer specializes Organization, and consequently, any employer pair, such as (Tom, IBM), is an instance of Organization, which is strange.
What is the reason for this non-standard construction in KerML's metamodel?

In KerML, features indeed represent relationships, but semantically, they classify sequences (for now, let us interpret this as some kind of navigation). If you look at them this way, navigating through the employer feature gets you to a set of Organizations, which is a subset of all the things classified as Organization. Therefore, employer is a kind of Organization.
Furthermore, one of the new features of SysML v2 is usage-oriented modeling, which lets you specialize a type in the context of its usage without creating a new, more special definition. This is supported by features being types and specializing their featured types. For example, you could say that (in addition to everything inherited from Organization), employer also has a feature salary.
Long story:
In ontologies, semantics are generally given in terms of classification. The set of elements classified by a type is called its extent. The set of things being classified is generally referred to as the universe (often extended by the set of all possible pairs of those things, or in KerML, N-tuples that we call sequences). The mapping from the model elements to the extents is called an interpretation. The semantics is then given by defining axioms and instantiating them for every model element. his results in a set of assertions about the extents and their relationships, allowing us to check if a given universe and interpretation satisfies the model.
The fact that features specialize their featured types means that the extent of Organization will contain sequences of length two (and more). There is an axiom that if this is the case, the extent must also contain the 1-tail of these sequences (i.e., if Tom's employer is IBM, IBM is an Organization). However, IBM itself is not an employer. It can be the value of an employer (when it is paired with a person), but not an employer itself.
The less intuitive part is that the extent of Organization will now contain both IBM and Tom's employer (the value of which is also IBM, but the instance of the feature is actually a pair now). The extent of salary will contain triples: a person, an organization, and a number. We can see that this allows employers of different people to have different salaries assigned to them, even if they are the same company.
To understand this, we have to observe that the KerML semantics is defined similarly to other ontologies, and it is not reduced to a labeled graph, as one might expect, but to assertions about the presence or absence of navigations on such a graph (but this interpretation is not mandatory). So the semantics really says that if you look at your universe and your interpretation (which is a function from model elements to sets of sequences, without providing further interpretation), you have to:

find IBM, classified as Organization
find a sequence (Tom, IBM), classified as employer and Organization.

The above assumes you want to include IBM and Tom in your universe. As noted above, the semantics will only give you assertions that you can use to check if your universe and interpretation satisfy the model. It will not (or only very rarely) force you to include something in any of them, let alone instruct you on how to build them.

Thanks for your answer, which is useful (so I have upvoted it), but not yet satisfactory. I understand that the projection of the binary relation employer to its second column subsets Organization (so, we say "employers are organizations"), but the attribute employer itself does not subset the classifier Organization. Therefore, I don't see that this would create a reason for the strange choice made in KerML's semantics to include tuples/sequences in the extent of classifiers.

It seems that KerML made this choice that features, like employer, are not just plain attributes (with the semantics of a binary relation), but also subtypes of their 'featured type' (i.e., their co-domain), like employer being a subtype of Organization, for allowing to define features of features, like defining the attribute Person::employer::salary, while inheriting all features of Organization. However, this comes at a cost: the blown-up concept of KerML interpretations has no longer the philosophical appeal of Tarskian model theory as a correspondence theory of truth.

Can you please add some remarks in your answer explaining if there has been any discussion of this issue (blowing up the interpretation/extent of classifiers by adding sequences violates the philosophical foundation of model-theoretic semantics) in the SysML submission group?

You gave the answer in your second comment, this is exactly the reason. The benefits manifest at the SysML level, where one can fine-tune a part at the place of usage without having to create a new, specialized definition. This gives an elegant and simple way to model configurations of "standard" components (e.g., from a component library).

Regarding the discussion, unfortunately, I was not there from the beginning. However, there have been discussions about the way we define semantics from time to time, and I have criticized the current approach a couple of times for more-or-less the same reasons (I have to familiarize myself with Tarski's work, though - coming from formal methods, my motivations have slightly different foundations). We still have some open discussions, but these are mostly private conversations with other members involved in semantics. The concensus, though, is that we have bigger problems until the release.

I would suggest raising this question in the SysML v2 Release Group: https://groups.google.com/g/sysml-v2-release

In fact, I had asked this question in their Google Group, but did not get any answer.
